# Read a large excel file and append large rows in it

Tags: java, apache-poi, large-data

Here is a requirement:
  Client will produce some data(very large about 200 thousand rows) and Server generate excel file with the data.
  Client can not fetch these data for one time for some unchangeable reason.So, they Post data(JSON) for many times. And I generate some excel files with every single JSON data. 
  The Problem is: how to read a large excel file and append large rows in it ? Or any good solution ? 
   For example: the data has 200 thousand rows. Client will Post data for 5 times and 40 thousand data will be posted every time 
Note: excel is xlsx extension  (2007+ version )
BTW: SXSSFWorkbook can write very huge file. But how I load the large excel file and not cause OOM

Comment: Depending on the excel version you will already run into problems with the data requiring more rows than a sheet can offer. Until Excel 2007 a maximum of 65536 rows was on one sheet... I would say the best solution would be to not use Excel. I am assuming that's not an option?

Comment: Thanks ben. The excel is xlsx

Comment: Even if possible (Excel 2007), the Excel should not be data storage for 200,000 data records. For this a database should be used. This database could store the 4 x 50,000 data records got via JSON. Then the Excel file could be created whole at once using `SXSSF` with data from the database. Else the overhead (opening the `ZIPPackage`, getting the sheets `XML`, appending 50,000 rows, rewriting the `ZIPPackage`) will be much high for memory usage as well as for time usage.

Comment: Thanks Axel. I search many about this. And i found a solution from you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805878/add-content-to-a-very-large-excel-file-using-apache-poi-run-out-of-alternatives/35826943#35826943   but the method ctcell.setV()  is confused. when i set letter not Integer . The excel generated indeed but show error (Excel found unreadable content)when open it . The content is right.   Plz HELP.

Comment: @robot3: "the method ctcell.setV() is confused. when i set letter not Integer":  You seems not have understand how it works. The `ctcell.setV` **always** sets a numeric  value. This is either the `double` numeric cell value or the `int` `sRef` which was previous got via `int sRef = sharedstringstable.addEntry(ctstr);` while setting the string cell value into the `SharedStringsTable sharedstringstable`.

Comment: Yes.Indeed. I read the code again. Now, I have another question. How to copy style from one excel sheet to another when appending. I know method " ctCell.setS " is to set style. And I tried StyleTable to create style and copy from another . But It did not work . The style seems different from it. Can you show me some code block about copy style when appending from different sheet. Thanks again . I want to vote you or something . but my reputation limit, sorry about that. I hope I did not disturb you

Comment: @robot3: Using the low level approaches there are not general solutions to questions like "How to copy style?". Only very special solutions are possible and very good knowledge about the internals of the Office Open XML file system is needed. But cell styles are on workbook level and not on sheet level. So if you do `CTCell.setS(long s)` set the same `long s` as got via `CTCell.getS()` from another cell in a sheet of the same workbook then this both cells should show the same style then. Of course this will not work using different workbooks.